# Trouble Finding Maximum Error in Taylor Polynomials (Lagrange Error Bound)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I've been trying to calculate the maximum possible error for the Taylor Series (with $n=3$, $c=0$, $|x| \leq .1$) of the function $f(x)=(1+2x)^{-4}$ Here's my work:

$$f(x)=(1+2x)^{-4}$$
$$f'(x)=-8(1+2x)^{-5}$$
$$f''(x)=80(1+2x)^{-6}$$
$$f'''(x)=-960(1+2x)^{-7}$$
$$f''''(x)=13440(1+2x)^{-8}$$

Now we know, $$|R_n| \leq |\frac{f^{n+1}(z)(x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}|$$

Plugging values in,

$$R_3 \leq \frac{13440(1+2z)^{-8}(x)^{4}}{(4)!}$$
$$R_3 \leq \frac{13440x^{4}}{4!(1+2z)^{8}}$$
$$R_3 \leq \frac{560x^{4}}{(1+2z)^{8}}$$

Now, since $c \leq z \leq x$, we have

$$0 \leq z \leq .1$$

Thus,

$$(1+2z)^8 \leq 1.2^8$$

Now we have,

$$R_3 \leq \frac{560(.1)^4}{1.2^8} \approx .013$$

But my book has

$$R_3 \leq .34$$

Where did I go wrong? Thanks

Comment: If $f(z)\le a$ then $\frac1{f(z)}\ge\frac1a$

Comment: @PeterForeman Ah, thank you---I didn't think about using that. But how would I use it to find the maximum possible value of $f(z)$ since I know only know what $f(z)$ is greater than?

Comment: $
(1 + 2z)^8  \le 1.2^8$ implies $\frac{1}{{(1 + 2z)^8 }} \ge \frac{1}{{1.2^8 }}
$ and not the other way around.

Comment: @Gary Thanks, Gary. This is what Peter Foreman said, so now I'm trying to figure out how to maximize $f(z).$ How would I go about doing this?

Comment: $(1 + 2z)^8  \ge (1 - 2 \cdot 0.1)^8$ since, by assumption, $-0.1\leq x\leq 0.1$. Note that $z$ is either between $0$ and $x$ or between $x$ and $0$, depending on whether $x>0$ or $x< 0$.

Comment: @Gary Oh, that makes perfect sense. Thanks!